# Accessing attributes named as numbers

Tags: json, node.js

I 'm working in node.js and I have to parse the following object;

```
{ state:
   {
      desired: { '1': '0', '151': '2', hdr: [Object] },
      reported: { '1': '0', '151': '2', hdr: [Object] } 
   }
}
```

I can access values like;

state.desired

state.desired.hdr[0]

but how can I access the attribute/value '1':'0'  or '151':'2' ?

If I try like;

state.desired.151 
or 
state.desired.'151'

I get error...

Thanks
Gus

Comment: state.desired['151']

Comment: `state.desired[1]` ,  `state.desired[151]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  state.desired['151'] or state['desired']['151'];

If you want to get the value from an object where key is number or special character then, use this format:  **obj['key']**

i.e

`let myObj = { 
        "1": "foo",
        "-" : "bar"
     }
   console.log(myObj['1']); // foo
   console.log(myObj['-']); // bar`